# Most efficient way to sum over matrix products?

Tags: matrix

I have two lists.  The first, `coefficientlist`, is dense and has dimension `{176,176}` elements.  The second, `cubelist`, is a list of three-dimensional lists, i.e. `cubelist` has dimension `{176,65,65,65}`.  I need to perform the following summation:

```
    sumlist=Table[0,{65},{65},{65}];
    Do[
    If[coefficientlist[[n,m]]!=0,
      sumlist += coefficientlist[[n,m]] (cubelist[[n]]cubelist[[m]]) ];
      ,{n,176},{m,176}];
```

Essentially I want to perform a sum like $S = \sum\limits_{i ,j} T_{ij} \phi_i \phi_j $ where the $T$ matrix is called `coefficientlist` in the code above and the $\phi_i$ are represented as grids over real space.

I have to do this several times, so I want to find the most efficient way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code simply doesn't work for me... `Table[0,{65},{65},{65}]` generates a large matrix of... zeros! So the sum must be zero too...

Comment: @Rod Lm  The sum is zero even if the matrix is really, really large? ;}

Comment: @RodLm I think `sumlist` is a container to record the sum, `sumlist=Table[0,{65},{65},{65}]` is merely an initialization.

Comment: Another question: if `cubelist` is three-dimensional, how can it have Dimension `{176,65,65,65}`?

Comment: That isn't really a problem.  I initialize the table as having zeroes in every element.  In order for the Do loop to add to it with each step using the `+=`, `sumlist` has to be a list.  I suppose I could have it be a list with `Null` at each element, but I don't think that would make a difference.

Comment: It is a list of three dimensional lists.  As in, each element of `cubelist` is has dimension `{65,65,65}`

Comment: @DavidCarraher No?

Comment: @RodLm Did I answer your questions?  `sumlist` is only a large matrix of zeroes before the `Do` loop executes.

Comment: @user7268 Yes, you did.

Comment: @Rod Lm    Correct. I was just having a little fun.

Comment: As much as I hate it when people whine about being downvoted on reddit, I have to ask why this got downvoted here?  This place isn't all that friendly to people who come here asking for help, is why I always use a new throwaway account whenever I do come here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method with new tensor functions introduced in Mathematica 9:

```
coefficientlist = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 3}];
cubelist = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 5, 5, 5}];

tensor = Fold[
   TensorContract[TensorProduct[#1, cubelist], #2] &,
   coefficientlist,
   {{{1, 3}}, {{1, 5}}}
   ];

sum = Outer[tensor[[##, ##]] & @@ {#1, #2, #3} &, Range[5], Range[5], Range[5]]
```

## Edit

As I tested with your original scale, both @0x4A4D's method and mine will need lots of memory due to large intermediate arrays. So if you are running short of RAM, like me, `Compile` your original version might be a better choice.

```
funcComp = Compile[{{coefficientlist, _Real, 2}, {cubelist, _Real, 4}},
  Module[{sumlist, l},
   sumlist = 0 cubelist[[1]];
   l = Dimensions[coefficientlist][[1]];
   Do[sumlist += 
     coefficientlist[[n, m]] (cubelist[[n]] cubelist[[m]]),
      {n, l}, {m, l}];
   sumlist
   ]]
```

Test on a random data:

```
j = 100;
k = 30;
coefficientlist = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {j, j}];
cubelist = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {j, k, k, k}];

AbsoluteTiming[sum = funcComp[coefficientlist, cubelist];]
```

> {4.368250,Null}

```
sumlist = 0 cubelist[[1]];
AbsoluteTiming[
 Do[sumlist += 
   coefficientlist[[n, m]] (cubelist[[n]] cubelist[[m]]),
    {n, j}, {m, j}]]
```

> {7.961455,Null}

```
sumlist == sum
```

> True

Comment: That's great!  Originally when you said to use compile, I did something like `func=Compile[{{n,_Integer},{m,_Integer}},coefficientlist[[n, m]] (cubelist[[n]] cubelist[[m]])]`, but didn't see any speedup.

Comment: Then, I tried copying from your example, and it took a fraction of a second, and thought "WOW!" before I realized you had the summation running from 1 to 3, LOL.

But even doing the full summation, it dropped the time needed from ~1100 seconds to 123 seconds.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Since both sums have different ranges how can sumlist == sum? You probably should change the ranges and timing of the second sum.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Sorry for the mistake.. It is indeed equal due to a same initialization and computing process, which could be my excuse of the oversight..(also too late/early to have a clear brain here. :-/ Anyway, please see my edit.

Comment: @user7268 Glad I can help:) Please see my edit on the `Compile` part.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, here is a loop-free method:

```
Total[coefficientlist Outer[Times, cubelist, cubelist, 1], 2]
```

There surely are more efficient methods, tho.

Comment: The problem here is that generating the matrix `Outer[Times, cubelist, cubelist, 1]`, which would have dimension `{176,176,65,65,65}`, takes too much memory and causes the system to crash.  Also, does `MapThread` help this to be more efficient?  I would have just tried `Total[coefficientlist Outer[Times, cubelist, cubelist, 1],2]` since it assumes element by element multiplication anyway.

Comment: Hmm, right; the Hadamard multiplication can be done more directly. I'll edit. On a hunch, what are the results of ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[cubelist]`` and ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[coefficientlist]``?

Comment: Hah, it does have a name!  Thank you for that piece of information, 0x4A4D.

Comment: You haven't answered my question yet... did you try executing those two snippets?

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question, I did run those and the answer is False.  I can't find from the online documentation what PackedArrays are good for.  Converting the arrays in question into PackedArrays didn't improve the performance of the solution Silvia posted.

Comment: @user, to clarify: after doing ``cubelist = Developer`ToPackedArray[cubelist]; coefficientlist = Developer`ToPackedArray[coefficientlist];``, there still was no improvement in speed? At the very least, if, as you say, those are arrays of inexact numbers, they take up less memory than unpacked arrays.

Comment: Yes, I run the funcComp on the packed and normal versions and the timing is the same.